# How to convert a VARCHAR column to a Timestamp in a table

Tags: amazon-athena, apache-superset

I am trying to convert a `VARCHAR` column from a table into a `TIMESTAMP`.

Currently my column looks like this:

```
2020-05-31T05:00:21Z
```

My goal is to transform this column in to a timestamp so I can use it for a visualization (Big Number with Trendline)

When I leave the column as it is, I get this error:

```
awsathena error: INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to timestamp: 2020-07-07T18:56:56Z
```

When I change the type of the column to `TIMESTAMP`, I get this other error:

```
awsathena error: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 4:19: '>=' cannot be applied to varchar, timestamp with time zone
```

This is the query from the visualization:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', CAST("eventtime" AS TIMESTAMP)) AS "__timestamp",
       COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM "cloudtrail_logs_cloud_trail_elk"
WHERE "eventtime" >= '2020-07-01 00:00:00.000000'
  AND "eventtime" < '2020-07-08 00:00:00.000000'
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', CAST("eventtime" AS TIMESTAMP))
ORDER BY "count" DESC
LIMIT 50000;
```

Is there any way of changing the type of this column so I can use it for my visualization?

Comment: Could you tell us the query you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi @EduardoYáñezParareda, I edited the Question, now it includes the Query from the visualization

Answer (score 1):

In case someone runs in to the same Problem as i did, you can use this function:

```
from_iso8601_timestamp(eventtime)
```

in Superset here: Superser -> Edit Table -> Edit Column -> Expression

[Superser-> Edit Table-> Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXyZQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to do the casting on the datetimes values:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', CAST("eventtime" AS TIMESTAMP)) AS "__timestamp",
       COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM "cloudtrail_logs_cloud_trail_elk"
WHERE "eventtime" >= TIMESTAMP '2020-07-01 00:00:00'
  AND "eventtime" < TIMESTAMP '2020-07-08 00:00:00'
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', CAST("eventtime" AS TIMESTAMP))
ORDER BY "count" DESC
LIMIT 50000;
```

or using `between` instead of `>=` and `<`

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', CAST("eventtime" AS TIMESTAMP)) AS "__timestamp",
       COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM "cloudtrail_logs_cloud_trail_elk"
WHERE "eventtime" between TIMESTAMP '2020-07-01 00:00:00'
  AND TIMESTAMP '2020-07-08 00:00:00'
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', CAST("eventtime" AS TIMESTAMP))
ORDER BY "count" DESC
LIMIT 50000;
```